# Is it possible to create custom entities (entries if you take up the strapi vocabulary) in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

**Edit : the thing I was looking for is called [Custom Post Type](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/) in the WordPress World**

---

Disclaimer: it is my first steps with WordPress and I realize I do not have the right vocabulary to make a proper google search, so please excuse me if this answer has been already asked many times ...

I'm working on a website that use an old preexisting WordPress as headless CMS.

On this new website, I need to display some "job offers"

On the preexisting WordPress, those job offers are just HTML blocks embedded in a page. So I can't get only those without having the embedded page HTML and CSS

If I could have created a custom REST API to get those "job offers", I would have said that those resources would look like this :

```
{
  title : string,
  description: string
}
```

My first idea would be to create a WordPress custom end point, but I do not know if it is possible to create custom entities (entries (?) If I take up the vocabulary of strapi)

Is this something that can be done?

I've tried :

- basic google search
- reading the strapi and wordpress documentation

I expect to be referred to a solution or to know what to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're looking for are [Custom post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/) if that can help a plugin called [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) can help with the custom fields.